# Eclipse Selenium Facebook login issue (new page email) driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(""); Java

Tags: java, eclipse, email, selenium, facebook-login

I am trying to login facebook but there is a problem.

I want to write "email" to facebook login page, but it's writing to my website's login page.

i don't want to write email to email input of site.com, i want to write email to facebook login input which is opened pop-up.

Here is the part of my code:

```
        driver.get("http://www.example.com");
    //click login
    driver.findElement(By.className("btnSignIn")).click();
    //If it's not login already with Facebook account; wants username and password.
    driver.findElement(By.className("facebookBtn")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("selenium");
```

All code:

```
package com.example.tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class ExampleLogin {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Create Firefox driver to drive the browser
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //Create Chrome driver to drive the browser
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
    //"C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\selenium-java-2.46.0\\chromedriver.exe");

    //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    //Open Site Homepage
    driver.get("http://www.example.com");
    //click login
    driver.findElement(By.className("btnSignIn")).click();
    //If it's not login already with Facebook account; wants username and password.
    driver.findElement(By.className("facebookBtn")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("selenium");

    //After login, browser will go http://www.example.com address and will confirm the login status.        

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since its opening in a different popup you need to first switch to that window (popup) before doing any operation. Try to first get the window object of the popup and then Switch to the window the try to write the email. Below code will help to find the window. Customise it accordingly

```
Set<String> windowId = driver.getWindowHandles();    // get  window id of current window
    Iterator<String> itererator = windowId.iterator();   

    String mainWinID = itererator.next();
    String  newAdwinID = itererator.next();

    driver.switchTo().window(newAdwinID);
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
   // perform the operation on the popup driver.operations
```